# My laptop can't find a device that is connected to a my router but my other laptop can find it

Tags: networking, udp, ip, router, laptop

I have this device that uses port 80000 and UDP. It came with a program that communicates with it. However, my laptop (laptop A) can't find that device using the program. So I tested the program to my other laptop (laptop B) and it can find the device and was able to communicate with it. I've check firewall issues but no luck.

Laptop A and B differences:
OS: A-Windows 8
    B-Windows 7
-but OS was not a problem. I have successfully run the program from the last time I used it. I never did any configurations that might affect it. As far a I can remember, I installed programs like Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your network settings are different. That is something you have to find out yourself, since we cannot tell you.

The best and most reliable way to debug networking issues is to snif the network traffic: take a dump tool like `tcpdump` or `wireshark`, make single requests from both systems whilst the network has low traffic and filter out the requests. Then you can compare both requests and tell the difference. This is your answer and probably you can decide what you have to change to make both requests look the same.